# How do I know if Storyboard is starting to reverse?

Tags: silverlight, animation, storyboard, expression-blend

I have an animated image in Expression Blend 4.0. I have implemented a Storyboard for it and I set the `AutoReverse` property to True.

I need to perform an operation when my Storyboard completes, before it reverses. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split your auto-reversing Storyboard into two without auto-reverse. Add a [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) handler to the first Storyboard that performs any desired action before it starts the second Storyboard.